# Getting values from JSP one to servlet one and sending it to another jsp and servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp say  index.jsp it has a form and users enter details in it.I retrieve entered details using one.servlet and I validate those entered details.

Next I have to pass those values to another jsp say results.jsp which will dispaly the results in web page and asks for confirmation.At this point i want to know whether its a good practice to use session or setattribute?

Further result.jsp will send these details to another servlet called two.servlet where it will store those values in database.

So i want to know whether using session will help me to complete my task

Comment: Why not just go the HTML way of `POST`ing the values or passing them via `GET` parameters?

Comment: Why do you go for a session when the JSP fields will be available with request object? Just pass-on the values from servlet to JSP with request.setAttribute(). Try to avoid session here, unless you have some other criteria!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common pattern is as follow :

- [ a servlet prepares eventually data for the JSP containing the form ]
- a JSP displays the form
- a servlet takes the element from the form processes them and validates the input

  - if input is not acceptable forward back to first JSP
  - if input is acceptable, saves to database and redirects(*) to another page

If you want to add a confirmation phase, you should put it in the middle :

- first JSP diplays the form
- validation servlet validates the input and if Ok forward to a confirmation JSP
- confirmation JSP displays data and a very simple form (Ok/Cancel)
- final servlet take the result of the second form, saves the data in database and redirects as for the simple case.

The hard part in this second pattern is that you have to pass the input data to the final servlet. Session is an option, but you must consistently remove stale data from the session if the user takes any other action, for example passes an url to another part of the application directly from the URL bar (or from its favorites). Even if it uses more bandwidth, I prefere pass all relevant data in hidden fields.

As it is more complex, and after all the user has first to click on a submit button, the confirmation phase is often omitted. I you really need that, you could look at dedicated frameworks such as Spring WebFlow.

But I must admit all that is just the way I like ...

(*) this POST redirect GET pattern avoids that the browser asks the user if he wants to send again data when he presses the back arrow

Answer (score 0):

I can understand your problem but i think you don't need two separate servlets(one for validation and another for saving) instead after doing your validation you can save it on db and then you could show the result in result.jsp via session or query strings

Comment: But i want the user to confirm his entered details

Comment: For that you could do in view part i mean html part itself